# Symfony routing problem, route being ignored

Tags: routes, symfony1

I have the following in my `app/frontend/config/routing.yml`:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: main, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*

sf_guard_register:
  url:   /register
  param: { module: user, action: register }

sf_guard_signin:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
  url:   /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_password:
  url:   /request_password
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: password }
```

When I try the `/register` route, I get this:

> Action "register/index" does not exist.

I should specify, I don't have a "register" module, and my user module is working well if called manually. Plus the other routes are working fine.

Any ideas are welcomed, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line with jeremy's answer:

Because your `default_index` route is placed above, going to `/register` causes this route to match. Since it is located before the `sf_guard_register` route, only the first match "counts".

Your routing.yml should look like this:

```
sf_guard_register:
  url: /register
  param: { module: user, action: register }

sf_guard_signin:
  url: /login
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
  url: /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_password:
  url: /request_password
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: password }

homepage:
  url: /
  param: { module: main, action: index }

default_index:
  url: /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url: /:module/:action/*
```

Also, there are a number of best-practises that you might want to follow:

1. Disabling the default routes and relying solely on named routing such as `@homepage` is faster than having symfony figure out which route to match when using `url_for` or `link_to` helpers. Therefore, disable the default routing and create the routes yourself. Then, use the name of the route when generating URLs.
2. The routes used most often should be placed at the top, for example if you have a register link on all pages, you should place `sf_guard_register` at the top.

Just my 5 cents - hope you find it useful ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works, and your suggestions are quite savvy. :)

Answer (score 1):

Routes are processed in the order they are listed in your `routing.yml` file. Thus, the url /register matches the default_index route before it gets to sf_guard_register. Both default_index and default should go at the bottom of your `routing.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should even delete the 2 default routes :

```
default_index:
  url: /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url: /:module/:action/*
```

As it is bad practice to use them, and should always create a specific route.

The best way to add routes, is to PREPEND them to you file, adding each new route at the very top.

Also, a good way to debug your routing in frontend is to run :

```
symfony app:routes frontend
```

so you will see wich route maches what (and its requirements if any)